# Subquery return all rows if no match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm using a `JSON` object to filter data in my `WHERE` clause. If there's a match found return those rows, however, if there're NO match return ALL rows.

Here's a sample example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
   Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   SomeObject varchar(20),
   SomeText varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO MyTable(SomeObject, SomeText) VALUES ('hello', 'test1')
INSERT INTO MyTable(SomeObject, SomeText) VALUES ('yellow', 'test2')
INSERT INTO MyTable(SomeObject, SomeText) VALUES ('test1', 'test1')
```

The `JSON` filter used:

```
DECLARE @Filter nvarchar(MAX)
SET @Filter = N'{
  "SomeObject": "ello,yel"
}'
```

In the following example, to get the the rows with partial text of `ello and yel` in `SomeObject` column, I have the following working query.

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject'), ',') 
   WHERE (mt.SomeObject LIKE CONCAT('%', [Value], '%'))
```

But if I change my filter and don't specify `SomeObject`

```
SET @Filter = N'{
}'
```

the above query will no longer work since there're no matches found. To fix the issue, I have tried the following two queries, but still not getting the correct output.

1.

```
 --This query will ALWAYS return all the rows regardless of the filter being passed even though some of those will have a match.
SELECT mt.*
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT ISNULL(
   (
     SELECT *
     FROM STRING_SPLIT(JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject'), ',') 
     WHERE (mt.SomeObject LIKE CONCAT('%', [Value], '%'))
    ),0)
 )
```

2.

```
--Works ONLY if filter specified. If filter is missing will not return all rows.
SELECT mt.*
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject'), ',') 
   WHERE (mt.SomeObject IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter, N'$.SomeObject') IS 
      NULL OR mt.SomeObject LIKE CONCAT('%', [Value], '%'))
)
```

Any suggestion on how I can return ALL the rows if no match found in the `subquery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your filter by default as you have above, which is `{` and `CR` then `}` then you can account for this as the default:

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject'), ',') 
   WHERE (mt.SomeObject LIKE CONCAT('%', [Value], '%')))
   OR replace(@Filter,char(10),'') = '{}'
```

Otherwise, you can account for it the same way by setting the variable to `NULL` or a blank space or whatever. See the demo here: [**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=77972150c4f3afb7facc6a53d66e795e)